# Jmeter - Future timestamp

Tags: java, jmeter

im trying to create a parameter in Jmeter that gives the current timestamp + 5 minutes. Does anyone know how to do this? To generate the current timestamp i have this: ${__time(HH:mm:ss,TIMESTAMP)}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid that [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function doesn't provide enough flexibility. You'll need to calculate this date value via [Beanshell Sampler or Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Relevant Beanshell code will look like

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

Date now = new Date(); // get current time
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Java Calendar instance
c.setTime(now); // set Calendar time to now
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5); // add 5 minutes to current time
Date now_plus_5_minutes = c.getTime(); // get Date value for amended time
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); // create a formatter for date       
String mydate = sdf.format(now_plus_5_minutes); // format date as string
vars.put("mydate",mydate); // save date to JMeter variable named "mydate"
```

You'll be able to refer that `mydate` value as

- ${mydate}
- ${__V(mydate)}

In the place you'll need to provide that updated date.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

had  to use but for future date in terms of days:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
    import java.util.Date; 

    Date date = new Date(); 
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+5); 
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    // or: SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    String formattedDate = df.format(date); 
    vars.put("myFutureDate",formattedDate);
```

the block of code above you are supposed to put into **BeanShellPreprocessor**:
[image]

To call a variable date in appropriate place -

```
${myFutureDate}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the __javaScript command as your parameter http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript.  This will give you the timestamp in seconds since epoch.

`${__javaScript( Math.floor( ( Date.now() + ( 5 * 60 * 1000 ) ) / 1000 ) )}`

[image: Using __javaScript as parameter]

Example  of [JMeter Test with JMX File](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11593)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-line solution I suggest:

```
${__groovy(use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) { (new Date() + 5.minutes).format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS') })}
```

Time offset is based on Groovy's `TimeCategory` http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html and is super easy to read and use (e.g. you can replace `5.minutes` with `1.day` or so).

Comparing to Dmitri's and Eugene's answers, the solution above is much shorter, doesn't require defining any additional config and is evaluated every time (so it can be used multiple times in the JMeter script).

JavaScript in Richard's answer is not recommended to be used in JMeter:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript

Groovy is also better in terms of date manipulation (thanks to `TimeCategory`) and date formatting.

Tested on JMeter 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function for this

```
${__timeShift(HH:mm:ss,,P5M,,)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are are 2 easy ways
Using Bean shell pre-processor:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
int AddSeconds= 00; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddMinutes= 32; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
int AddHours= 06; //this variable needs to be customized as per your need
 Date now         = new Date();
Calendar c       = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(now);
c.add(Calendar.SECOND, AddSeconds);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, AddMinutes);
c.add(Calendar.HOUR,   AddHours);
Date NewTime        = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String mytime       = df.format(NewTime);

vars.put("NewTime",mytime);
```

2nd way is this : "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,PT393M,,)}"

Comment: 2nd way is this :  "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z',,PT393M,,)}",

Comment: Please edit the second way into your answer.