# How do you pass in timestamp variable into JDBC request for jmeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, postgis

I am learning to use jmeter (for the first time) to do some performance testing against our geospatial postgres (postgis) database.  I want to use a JDBC Request sampler sql query to continually hit the database, however I need to alter the timestamps in the query, the problem is they aren't normal parameters, they are inside a string in a function call.

```sql
SELECT int_temp_f,
       observed_utc,
       encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geometry_4326"),'NDR'),'hex') AS geom,
       "ogc_featureid"
FROM fn_surfaceobs_temperature(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180 -90,-180 90,180 90,180 -90,-180 -90))',4326),
                                NULL,
                                0,
                                'latest',
                                'observed >= ''2015-06-08 14:00:00Z'' AND observed < ''2015-06-09 15:00:00Z'' ',
                                TRUE)
WHERE (geometry_4326 && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180 -90,-180 90,180 90,180 -90,-180 -90))',4326))
ORDER BY COALESCE(priority,0) DESC, observed DESC;
```

**How can I use jmeter variables to replace a user definition inside the string?**

```
'observed >= ''2015-06-08 14:00:00Z'' AND observed < ''2015-06-09 15:00:00Z'' ',
```

I want to do something like this:

```
'observed >= ''${start_timestamp}'' AND observed < ''${end_timestamp}'' ',
```

Is this even possible?

Ultimately I want to update the timestamps to always be 'today'.  But after looking into how to do timestamp variable in a normal SQL substitution situation I think I'm ok settling for just having to replace the timestamps as a user defined variable for now.

Comment: What sampler are you using?

Comment: JDBC request sampler.

Comment: Something like this might work: `${__BeanShell(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))}`

Comment: well, what's inside the beanshell parenthesis is just java code to return current date in the specified format. The `${__BeanShell()}` directive in jmeter evaluates the code contained and replaces the entire string with that value at runtime - sort of like dynamic variable subsitution. [See here for more information](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell). I'm posting as a comment because I'm not certain this will work inside the query box of the JDBC sampler.

Comment: Looks like the correct way to use it, is like this: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-rFr8QXtqoyI/T5prpJ09yzI/AAAAAAAAANQ/cW8xIVfeWmw/s1600/para.png question marks in the query and the beanshell piece in the `Parameter Values` box

Comment: @RaGe -- I think you have put me on the right path.  I also just realized you can put ${var} right into the string and it will substitute.  So now all I need to do it build a beanshell preprocessor that creates the timestamp for me.

Comment: The beanshell comment led me to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846846/jmeter-future-timestamp

This showed me how to create a 'function' that builds the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use jmeter vars in JDBC queries.

```sql
SELECT int_temp_f,
       observed_utc,
       encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geometry_4326"),'NDR'),'hex') AS geom,
       "ogc_featureid"
FROM fn_surfaceobs_temperature(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180 -90,-180 90,180 90,180 -90,-180 -90))',4326),
    NULL,
    0,
    'latest',
    'observed >= ''${StartDate}'' AND observed < ''${EndDateHour}'' ',
    TRUE)
WHERE (geometry_4326 && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180 -90,-180 90,180 90,180 -90,-180 -90))',4326))
ORDER BY COALESCE(priority,0) DESC, observed DESC;
```

The trick here is to get a valid timestamp. As [RaGe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745574/rage) pointed out above, beanShell is the answer.

You can create a simple user assigned variable like this:

```java
${__BeanShell(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()))}
```

OR in my case, I needed to do some additional tinkering to the timestamps so I created a beanshell preprocessor.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21847313/2532408 has a couple explanations.

Here is what I put in mine:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Calendar;

int backhour = -5
int forehour = 1
int foremin = 5

Date date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");  // needs to be 2015-06-09 15:00:00Z
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // get Java Calendar instance
c.setTime(date); // set Calendar time to now
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

c.add(Calendar.HOUR, backhour); // add -X hours
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); // set the dateformat to use UTC
String startDate = df.format(c.getTime());   //create string of calendar object
vars.put("StartDate",startDate);   // set the jmeter var to StartDate

//set the next var 1 hour ahead
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, forehour); // add 1 hour 
String endDateHour = df.format(c.getTime());  //create string of calendar object
vars.put("EndDateHour",endDateHour);   // set the jmeter var to EndDate
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, -forehour); // minus the hour so we can resuse c
```

Comment: I was sorta hoping you would answer so I could give you credit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter's [__time()](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function right inside your SQL query,  it returns current date in the form controllable by a [SimpleDataFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern.

Comment: @MarcelWilson It's about "future" timestamp, if you need current time it's better to use __time() function as Beanshell causes some performance overhead.

Comment: Ahh, good to know.  I interpreted it as __time() was simple.  But as you say, in this case, simple is better.